# Selecting the name of a UIButton swift5

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift5

I have a UIButton called `picPressed`, this UIButton has a background image. I want to to be able to get the name of the buttons background image.
I am trying something like:

```
let hello = picPressed.backgroundImage.name()
Print(hello)
```

But  get an error saying:

```
value of type '(UIControl.State) -> UIImage?' has no member 'name'
```

How can  isolate this attribute in swift5?

Comment: Read the error message. UIImages do not have "names".

Comment: @matt the alternative to names is what i am trying to find out, I can't see an alternative in the documentation so i'm unsure if the text of the background image can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, buttons don't remember their names (or the name of the image you install into them.)

I suggest you create an object that manages a button, takes a filename for an image, and remembers that filename for later. (Alternately you could subclass UIButton, but that can get complex.)